# Enable AllowBypassKey based off password

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a created a database that has the AllowBypassKey shift key disabled. What I am trying to do is have a hidden box that when double clicked on pops up a box where the user must enter the password and then the AllowBypassKey is enabled. I have added the code I have written so far but I am getting a "Sub or Function not defined" for the SetProperties portion. I have shown the disable AllowBypassKey code as well.

Disable Bypass code:

```vb
Function ap_DisableShift()
On Error GoTo errDisableShift

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim prop As DAO.Property
Const conPropNotFound = 3270

Set db = CurrentDb()

db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = False

Exit Function

errDisableShift:
If Err = conPropNotFound Then
Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
dbBoolean, False)
db.Properties.Append prop
Resume Next
Else
MsgBox "Function 'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Double-Click Code (Error popping up!)

```vb
Private Sub Secret_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Err_bDisableBypassKey_Click
Dim strInput As String
Dim strMsg As String
Beep
strMsg = "Do you want to enable the Bypass Key"
strInput = InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg, Title:="Disable Bypass Key Password")
If strInput = "PASSWORD" Then
SetProperties "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, True
Beep
MsgBox "The Bypass Key has been enabled."
Else
Beep
SetProperties "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False
MsgBox "Incorrect ''AllowBypassKey'' Password!"
Exit Sub
End If
Exit_bDisableBypassKey_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_bDisableBypassKey_Click:
MsgBox "bDisableBypassKey_Click", Err.Number, Err.Description
Resume Exit_bDisableBypassKey_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Check for typos, also try changing the private to public.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Allen Browne's `SetPropertyDAO` and `HasProperty` functions to manage the *AllowBypassKey* setting.  (Source for those functions is [here](http://allenbrowne.com/AppPrintMgtCode.html#SetPropertyDAO); and also included at the bottom of this answer.)

Then to normally disable *AllowBypassKey* for all users at database start, create this function and call it from the `RunCode` action of your database's *AutoExec* macro:

```vb
Public Function StartUp()
    SetPropertyDAO CurrentDb, "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False
End Function
```

To allow your privileged user(s) to override that setting (IOW to enable *AllowBypassKey*), use this tested version of your *Secret_DblClick* procedure:

```vb
Private Sub Secret_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo Err_bDisableBypassKey_Click
    Beep
    strMsg = "Do you want to enable the Bypass Key"
    strInput = InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg, Title:="Disable Bypass Key Password")
    If strInput = "PASSWORD" Then
        SetPropertyDAO CurrentDb, "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, True
        Beep
        MsgBox "The Bypass Key has been enabled."
    Else
        Beep
        SetPropertyDAO CurrentDb, "AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False
        MsgBox "Incorrect 'AllowBypassKey' Password!"
    End If

Exit_bDisableBypassKey_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_bDisableBypassKey_Click:
    MsgBox "bDisableBypassKey_Click", Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Exit_bDisableBypassKey_Click
End Sub
```

---

```vb
Function SetPropertyDAO(obj As Object, strPropertyName As String, intType As Integer, _
    varValue As Variant, Optional strErrMsg As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'Purpose:   Set a property for an object, creating if necessary.
    'Arguments: obj = the object whose property should be set.
    '           strPropertyName = the name of the property to set.
    '           intType = the type of property (needed for creating)
    '           varValue = the value to set this property to.
    '           strErrMsg = string to append any error message to.

    If HasProperty(obj, strPropertyName) Then
        obj.Properties(strPropertyName) = varValue
    Else
        obj.Properties.Append obj.CreateProperty(strPropertyName, intType, varValue)
    End If
    SetPropertyDAO = True

ExitHandler:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    strErrMsg = strErrMsg & obj.Name & "." & strPropertyName & " not set to " & _
        varValue & ". Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function

Public Function HasProperty(obj As Object, strPropName As String) As Boolean
    'Purpose: Return true if the object has the property.
    Dim varDummy As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    varDummy = obj.Properties(strPropName)
    HasProperty = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```